# How to pass a JSON from Angular 7 to a Datatable component

Tags: angular, datatables, angular7, angular-datatables

I am using Angular7 and the Datatables library : https://datatables.net/

I want to pass the data from the backend .ts file to the from end component

My html looks like this:

```
  <table   datatable class="table table-striped dataTable"   [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" [dtOptions]="dtOptions"  >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sort</th>
      <th>Icon</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>id</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
```

My component like this:

```
export class myComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(DataTableDirective)
  dtElement: DataTableDirective;
  dtTrigger = new Subject();
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
    // DataTables.Settings={};
  menus_ajax:JSON;

 constructor(private myService: myService) { }
ngOnInit() {

    this.myService.getdata().subscribe((event: HttpEvent<JSON>) => {
        if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
             console.log('Loading data...');
             this.data = event.body;

        }
    });


    this.dtOptions = {
           'paging':false,'ordering':false,
            'ajax':{'url': this.data,'dataSrc':''},

            'columns':[{'title':'Sort','data':'sort'},{'title':'Icon','data':'icon'},
                     {'title':'Title','data':'title'},{'title':'id','data':'id'}]
    };
    this.dtTrigger.next();

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to request a typed response - https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response - which will give you data in the object with desired properties and that you can refer in the template.

Otherwise you can try 2 options - 
1. using JSON.parse() which converts JSON to object
2. using res.JSON() . example for that can be seen here - https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/angular-way

For rendering the trs & tds in template according to data you can refer to -
https://www.beyondjava.net/how-to-use-a-javascript-datatable-in-an-angular-application or 
https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/angular-way

where they have shown rendering trs & tds with component properties.

I hope this would be helpful.